# I need to retreive data where the variable = one thing, and also return data whereby the same matches for another variable

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables. Product, Extra and Link. The product table contains the original row, and then more rows which are based on the original. Then there are extras attached to the original and each variant, using the link table. Each variant has the extras attached to it as per the Link table, but also all of the extras that are attached to the original. I need to return all extras where the name of the variable = xx, and the output should include all extras attached to the original and the variant.

These are my tables

Product

```
Id     ProdName   Basedonvariantid
--------------------------------------------
123    Original   null
456    Product1a  123
789    Product1b  123
012    Product1c  123
987    Original   null
654    Product2a  987
321    Product2b  987
098    Product2c  987
```

Extra

```
Id     ExtraName
--------------------------------------------
1      Extra1
2      Extra2
3      Extra3
4      Extra4
5      Extra5
6      Extra6
7      Extra7
8      Extra8
```

Link

```
Id     Productid      Extraid
--------------------------------------------
a      123            1
b      123            3
c      123            5
d      456            2
e      789            4
f      012            6
g      987            1
h      987            2
i      987            4
j      654            3
k      321            5
l      098            6
m      098            7
n      098            8
```

I cant work it out. I can do the join but only to return the extra's attached to just the variant, i.e

```
select p.prodname, e.extraname
from Product p
join Link l on p.id=l.productid
join Extra e on e.id=l.extraid
where p.prodname in (
'Product1b', 
'Product2c'
)
```

In the front end system, it will show that Product1b has all the extras linked to Product1 and Product1b, and it will show that Product2c has all the extras linked to Product2 and Product2c.

How can I write a query that says 'give me all extras for product1b and 2c, and returns the following:

```
Prodname      Extraname
--------------------------------------------
Product1b        Extra1
Product1b        Extra3
Product1b        Extra4
Product1b        Extra5
Product2c        Extra1
Product2c        Extra2
Product2c        Extra4
Product2c        Extra6
Product2c        Extra7
Product2c        Extra8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `OR` in your join condition to the `link` table. This may not be the most efficient (where a UNION might be more efficient)

```
select p.prodname, e.extraname
from Product p
    join Link l on (p.id=l.productid OR p.basedonvariantid = l.productid)
    join Extra e on e.id=l.extraid
where p.prodname in (
    'Product1b', 
    'Product2c'
);
```

The `UNION` version of this would look like:

```
select p.prodname, e.extraname
from Product p
join Link l on p.id=l.productid
join Extra e on e.id=l.extraid
where p.prodname in (
'Product1b', 
'Product2c'
)
UNION ALL
select p.prodname, e.extraname
from Product p
join Link l on p.basedonvariantid=l.productid
join Extra e on e.id=l.extraid
where p.prodname in (
'Product1b', 
'Product2c'
)
```

Both will work as long as the `BasedonvariantID` never refers to another variant (which itself refers to a main id). If that's the case then you'll have to resort to a recursive query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I've just realised my table wasn't specific enough. I've just updated it, to show that all the original entries are named the same. Will either of your answers return the results I mentioned I needed, where the prodname will always refer to the variant, with no mention of the original

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Your WHERE predicate finds records in the `product` table with a name `Product1b` and `Product2c` and then looks at either the `id` of that record or the `BasedonvariantID` of that record. It NEVER even looks at the records with the name `Original`. All the information needed to go to the `Link` table and then onto the `Extra` table is contained in the `Product` record with either the name `Product1b` or `Product2c`.

Comment: You legend, I'll give it a go. Thank you